# android: Images as buttons with transparency on SurfaceView with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player, transparency, surfaceview

I have framed layout with `ImageView`, `SurfaceView` and control elements as overlaying `ImageView`. So, a `SurfaceView` is used to play media with `MediaPlayer`, and `ImageView` is used then `MediaPlayer` preparing media as a still image. Then OnPrepared `ImageView` with still image `setVisibility` - `GONE` and we play video. The problem is with control `ImageViews`. As they a png images with transparent graphics then overlaying on `ImageView` transparent area looks good, but then `MediaPlayer` playing video, transparent area of graphics look very tinted like we disable this controls...

Please help me in advise how to make controls to look the same overlaying `ImageView` and `SurfaceView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/svMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/still_image" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/controls"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ibtnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="ibtnClick"
        android:src="@drawable/start_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ibtnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="ibtnClick"
        android:src="@drawable/stop_image" />

</RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have been having the same issue for quite some time without resolution...

Answer (score 0):

i dunno how much this will help, but u can try setting the background colour of controls using

```
controls.setColor(Color.argb(00, 0, 0, 0));
```

The first arguments indicate alpha values responsible for transperency. setit to 00
values range from 00-255

Comment: maybe if you could upload a screen shot of how it is now,we can understand better what you want...

Comment: Strange, but I can't make normal screen shot while MediaPlayer is playing on SurfaceView, got a blank screen with only my controls at one..

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
logo.setAlpha(110);
```

Comment: This not help, whole image now transparent but again overlaying SurfaceView and ImageView looks a different... Maybe MediaPlayer is used some other alpha blending than ImageView?